# Search an array of arrays of objects with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

I have an array of an array of JToken objects. I would like to return a list of the top 10 objects ordered by the Severity member in descending order; right now, I'm just returning all issues where Severity < 3. I'm stumbling over accessing the inner array. Can anyone give me some guidance on how to query the data with Newtonsoft to get my desired results? TIA!

Some sample data:

```
[
  [
    {
      "IssueOrderNumber": 1,
      "Description": "Exhaust fumes leaking into Parts department.",
      "Resolution": "Increased outbound ventilation in Service area.",
      "Severity": 1
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "IssueOrderNumber": 1,
      "Description": "Houston, we have a problem.",
      "Resolution": "We are working on it.",
      "Severity": 1
    },
    {
      "IssueOrderNumber": 2,
      "Description": "We have issues with employee retention.",
      "Resolution": "We will start giving retention bonuses.",
      "Severity": 2
    },
    {
      "IssueOrderNumber": 3,
      "Description": "Increasing incidents of sexual harassment.",
      "Resolution": "Sexual harassment training is now doubled, and an independent investigator/arbitrator has been hired.",
      "Severity": 2
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "IssueOrderNumber": 1,
      "Description": "Deal worksheet left unattended on salesperson's desk",
      "Resolution": "Salesperson required training hours doubled",
      "Severity": 2
    },
    {
      "IssueOrderNumber": 2,
      "Description": "PII left exposed for customers submitting inquiries over Web",
      "Resolution": "Web site reengineered to encrypt PII",
      "Severity": 2
    },
    {
      "IssueOrderNumber": 3,
      "Description": "A hacker exposed PII for sales staff and managerial staff over the Web.",
      "Resolution": "Web site was patched",
      "Severity": 1
    }
  ]
]
```

My C#:

```
jArrIssues2 = JArray.Parse(strJArrIssues);
for (int i = 0; i < jArrIssues2.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < jArrIssues2[i].Count(); j++)
    { 
        JObject iss = JObject.Parse(jArrIssues2[i][j].ToString());
        JObject tmpObj = new JObject();
        int intSev = (int)iss["Severity"];
        string strDescr = (string)iss["Description"];
        if (intSev < 3) // Currently, getting all Sev 1, 2 issues;
                        // I'd rather get the top 10 issues ordered by severity
        { 
            tmpObj.AddFirst(new JProperty("Description", strDescr));
            tmpObj.Property("Description").AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("Severity", intSev));
            jArrUltimate.Add(tmpObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `jArrIssues2[i][j]` will be a `JObject` since because that is what `JArray.Parse(strJArrIssues)` will create for each element. So, `JObject.Parse(jArrIssues2[i][j].ToString())` is redundant and confusing. Also, trying to preserve property order in JSON objects is a sign of brittle code. Code should not depend on the order of properties in an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a class `Issue`, and using the Newtonsoft converter to put the JSON string into the class structure.  It will be much easier to deal with.

Then you can make use of [LINQ functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/) to sort, filter, or limit your results.

Note that I de-serialize into a `List<List<Issue>>`. That is because of the JSON structure you defined in your original post.  It's an odd structure; you may want to look at simplifying it.

The [`selectMany` LINQ call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-8.0) below will reduce the list of lists to a single list, making it easier to traverse.

See example code below.

```
public class Issue {
    public int IssueOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Resolution { get; set; }
    public int Severity { get; set; }
}


string json = @"[
    [
        {
        ""IssueOrderNumber"": 1,
        ""Description"": ""Exhaust fumes leaking into Parts department."",
        ""Resolution"": ""Increased outbound ventilation in Service area."",
        ""Severity"": 1
        }
    ],
    [
        {
        ""IssueOrderNumber"": 1,
        ""Description"": ""Houston, we have a problem."",
        ""Resolution"": ""We are working on it."",
        ""Severity"": 1
        },
        {
        ""IssueOrderNumber"": 2,
        ""Description"": ""We have issues with employee retention."",
        ""Resolution"": ""We will start giving retention bonuses."",
        ""Severity"": 2
        },
        {
        ""IssueOrderNumber"": 3,
        ""Description"": ""Increasing incidents of sexual harassment."",
        ""Resolution"": ""Sexual harassment training is now doubled, and an independent investigator/arbitrator has been hired."",
        ""Severity"": 2
        }
    ],
    [
        {
        ""IssueOrderNumber"": 1,
        ""Description"": ""Deal worksheet left unattended on salesperson's desk"",
        ""Resolution"": ""Salesperson required training hours doubled"",
        ""Severity"": 2
        },
        {
        ""IssueOrderNumber"": 2,
        ""Description"": ""PII left exposed for customers submitting inquiries over Web"",
        ""Resolution"": ""Web site reengineered to encrypt PII"",
        ""Severity"": 2
        },
        {
        ""IssueOrderNumber"": 3,
        ""Description"": ""A hacker exposed PII for sales staff and managerial staff over the Web."",
        ""Resolution"": ""Web site was patched"",
        ""Severity"": 1
        }
    ]
]";

// convert json to C# object
List<List<Issue>> issues = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<Issue>>>(json);

// get the top 10 severe issues using linq
List<Issue> topSevereIssues = issues.SelectMany(r => r).OrderByDescending(r => r.Severity).Take(10).ToList(); 

// turn back to JSON (if thats the final desired data format)
string topSevereIssuesJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(topSevereIssues);
```

Comment: Brilliant! All I needed to do was change OrderByDescending into OrderBy.  :-)